# How to set up the iOS Telegram Source Code

Tags: ios, installation, telegram

Hi I have downloaded the iOS source code for iOS but for some reason I cannot seem to find the place where the API_ID is anywhere. Please can you tell me where this information is in the source code so I can add in my own.

Answer (score 4):

Add a file called "config.h" beside `Telegraph.xcodeproj` and place this code in that:

```
    #define SETUP_API_ID(apiId) apiId = YOUR_API_ID;
    #define SETUP_API_HASH(apiHash) apiHash = YOUR_API_HASH;
```

Then replace `YOUR_API_ID` and `YOUR_API_HASH` with values obtained from [telegram api support](https://my.telegram.org/apps).

Then compile and enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the project search and put API, it`ll return the files where is.